# How to kill suspended process by name?

Tags: linux, process, kill

I got a bunch of suspended processes. `pkill` cannot kill them but pretend to do that.

This command actually works:

```
pkill -e SOMENAMEHERE | grep -Eo '[0-9]+' | xargs kill -9
```

but it's too long to type.

Is there a single command solution?

(we are not considering here aliases and complex commands with pipeline)

env: CentOS 7.6 / bash

Comment: `pkill` by default sends `SIGTERM` to the process. `kill -9`, if I'm not mistaken, is `KILL` or `SIGKILL` which is more agressive. What if you pass that signal to `pkill` by something in the lines of `pkill SOMENAMEHERE -s SIGKILL`?

Answer (score 0):

To kill all the processes in Linux with name SOMENAMEHERE you can use command

```
killall SOMENAMEHERE
```

to send specific signal to the process you can use

```
killall -s <sginal> SOMENAMEHERE
```

Be warned in other OS like Solaris for example this command do different things!

Comment: I may be wrong, but `kill` or `killall` cannot replace `pkill` in all situations. In `pkill` you can also specify the owner for instance. But I'm genuinely not sure...

Comment: @Pouya, you can use `-u` to specify the process owner in `killall` command